# Storage of oauth access token in Asana

Tags: asana

I am trying to implement Asana oAuth mechanism in my android application. I was successful in getting the access token after successful authentication and allowing access to my registered app. Is this token enough to perform API operations further ?? what are the corresponding URLs for the same?

Please help !!

Thanks

Comment: *Is this token enough to perform API operations further ??* **And what is written in the documentation?** *what are the corresponding URLs for the same?* **And what is written in the documentation?**

Comment: In documentation , it was mentioned to use the  API key , specific for  user. As i am new to using oAuth2, I am just trying to understand.

Comment: API Key is only used to get the token(at least in the oauth use case senario)

Comment: I will explain what i have done so far .. I have created an activity with a webview, which loads the authorization url   https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize with client id, secret and redirect uri. My webview loads the url (login screen of asana). After succesful authorization and allowing access to my registered app, i am able to get the access token from the redirect uri. so far authentication is completed , now i want to retrieve user information like user Id, workspace information etc. How to start with that . I hope i could be able to make my question understand.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the implicit grant flow by passing `response_type=token` when directing the user to https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize in order to get retrieve the `access_token` from the fragment of the redirect URI.

Once you have obtained the access_token you may use this token to make calls to the API by supplying it in the authorization header like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me
```